# About infinite products and Euler Gamma functions

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, closed-form-expressions, products

I am interested in knowing how to calculate infinite products like (or reading any reference about it):

$$\prod_{j=1}^{\infty}\left( 1-\left( \frac{x}{a+j\pi} \right) ^2 \right)$$

Inserting it into a Mathematica worksheet (Wolfram research), it returns the following beautiful formula:

$$\frac{\pi^2\Gamma(\frac{\pi+a}{\pi})^2}{\Gamma(\frac{a-x}{\pi})\Gamma(\frac{a+x}{\pi})}$$

where $\Gamma(x)$ is the Euler's Gamma function, and $x$ and $a$ are positive real numbers.

Thanks in advance,

Gustavo

Comment: Improve your  $\LaTeX$ formulas.

Comment: [Weierstrass products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem#The_Weierstrass_factorization_theorem)

Comment: According to Maple, you left out a factor $a^2 - x^2$ in the denominator.

Comment: In general there is no method to give closed formulae for infinite sums or products. The reason is simply that most expressions involving limits do not have any easier expression. So in a way every closed formula is a lucky accident.

Answer (score 3):

The Weierstrass product identity
$$ \frac{1}{\Gamma(z)} = e^{\gamma z} z \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1 + \frac{z}{n}\right) e^{-z/n}  $$
implies 
$$ \frac{\Gamma(s)^2}{\Gamma(s-z) \Gamma(s+z)} = \frac{s^2-z^2}{s^2}  \prod_{n=1}^\infty \left(1 - \frac{z^2}{(n+s)^2}\right)$$
(valid wherever you don't run into a division by $0$ or a pole of $\Gamma$).  You're essentially looking at the case $s = a/\pi$, $z = x/\pi$.

Comment: ...as linked to by @reuns in a comment above

Comment: As usually, simply great.